# How to access/refer/reuse the Odata field as a constant from VDM into another Application specific POJO Classes

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We have used cloud SDK(odata-generator-maven-plugin) and generated the VDM out of our EDMX(defined in xml) file. Now, want to refer some of the fields from VDM as a constant in our POJO class instead of re-defining as a constant in our class . I don’t find EDMX field/odataName declared as a variable with public specifier and the constant as well in VDM generated classes.

In the below example,

For example :
VDM snippet - ItemCDSViewForLineItem.java

```
@ODataField(odataName = "DraftUUID")
private UUID key_2;  
public final static ItemCDSViewForLineItemField<UUID> KEY_2 = new ItemCDSViewForLineItemField <UUID>("DraftUUID");
```

Edmx snippet:

```
`<Property Name="DraftUUID" Type="Edm.Guid" sap:label="Key"/>`
```

**Is there any way by which I can access or refer “DraftUUID” as a constant field in our own POJO class and reuse it ? Could you please suggest ?**

Thanks
Surendra

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Lombok as a dependency to your project to see the public Getters and Setters for these fields. More information can be obtained from [the documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java#using-the-odata-generator).

To also see them in your IDE you probably need to have a plugin installed [as described here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/sdk-java-troubleshooting-frequent-problems#compilation-failures-in-generated-odata-vdm-classes).

Answer (score 0):

The method [`EntityField#getFieldName`](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/com/sap/cloud/sdk/datamodel/odata/helper/EntityField.html#getFieldName--) should give you what you are looking for:

```java
ItemCDSViewForLineItem.KEY_2.getFieldName() // returns "DraftUUID"
```